# How to maximize expectations based on historical trials?

Tags: probability, bayesian

There are 10 multiple-choice questions, each of which has 4 options $A, B, C, D$.

There is only one correct answer. 1 point is awarded for the correct answer, and 0 points for the wrong answer.

let $\vec{s_i}$ represents the options for a trial, and $S_i$ represents the score for that trial.

Given $n$ historical trial results, how to choose options for this trial to maximize score expectations?

Comment: Are you using some particular probability model here?  The person setting the exam can always ensure your expected score is $1/4$ point per trial by choosing the correct answer with equal probabilities, independent of past history.

Comment: @RobertIsrael The same set of questions is used in each trial in the same arrangement, the difference is the result and score of each choice

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are only given the total score for each trial, not the scores on individual questions.

There are $4^{10} = 1048576$ possible ways to choose an answer for each question.
It's a large number if you're working by hand, but not much for a computer.  So
you just check which of these produce the observed results on the historical trials,
and of those that do choose one at random.